Docker build fails to find project (auth-svc) directory during COPY step
I'm trying to build a Docker container for my Go project using Docker Compose, but I'm running into an issue where Docker cannot find the auth-svc directory during the COPY step.
Here is my project structure:
/home/sohel/go/src/github.com/bizspace/
├── api-gateway
│   ├── deploy
│   │   └── Dockerfile
│   ├── ...
├── auth-svc
│   ├── deploy
│   │   └── Dockerfile
│   ├── ...
├── deploy
│   └── docker
│       ├── docker-compose.yml
│       └── postgres
│           └── init.sql
├── go.mod
├── go.sum

Dockerfile (auth-svc/deploy/Dockerfile):
# Build stage
FROM golang:1.22-alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /app

# Copy go.mod and go.sum from the project root
COPY go.mod go.sum ./

# Download all dependencies
RUN go mod download

# Copy the entire auth-svc directory
COPY auth-svc ./auth-svc

# Build the Go application
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o /bin/auth-svc ./auth-svc/cmd/main.go

# Final stage
FROM scratch
COPY --from=builder /bin/auth-svc /bin/auth-svc
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/auth-svc"]

docker-compose.yml (deploy/docker/docker-compose.yml):
version: '3.8'

services:
  auth-svc:
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: auth-svc/deploy/Dockerfile
    container_name: auth-svc
    ports:
      - "8081:8081" # Adjust ports as necessary
    environment:
      - ENV_VAR=example_value # Add any necessary environment variables

  api-gateway:
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: api-gateway/deploy/Dockerfile
    container_name: api-gateway
    ports:
      - "8080:8080" # Adjust ports as necessary
    depends_on:
      - auth-svc
    environment:
      - ENV_VAR=example_value # Add any necessary environment variables

  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: mydatabase
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./postgres/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge

Error Message:
[+] Building 1.1s (9/11) docker:default
 => [auth-svc internal] load build definition from Dockerfile 0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 495B 0.0s
 => [auth-svc internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/golang:1.22-alpine 1.0s
 => [auth-svc internal] load .dockerignore 0.0s
 => => transferring context: 777B 0.0s
 => [auth-svc builder 1/6] FROM docker.io/library/golang:1.22-alpine@sha256:8c9183f715b0b4eca05b8b3dbf59766aaedb41ec07477b132ee2891ac0110a07 0.0s
 => [auth-svc internal] load build context 0.0s
 => => transferring context: 54B 0.0s
 => CACHED [auth-svc builder 2/6] WORKDIR /app 0.0s
 => CACHED [auth-svc builder 3/6] COPY go.mod go.sum ./ 0.0s
 => CACHED [auth-svc builder 4/6] RUN go mod download 0.0s
 => ERROR [auth-svc builder 5/6] COPY auth-svc ./auth-svc 0.0s
------
 > [auth-svc builder 5/6] COPY auth-svc ./auth-svc:
------
failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref b3ad4ddd-1331-4638-81e6-5cd14faf3a25::z649uairbj5bqcw0v4kauu8gl: "/auth-svc": not found

Steps Taken:
Navigated to /home/sohel/go/src/github.com/bizspace/deploy/docker.
Ran the command docker-compose up --build.
Questions:
Why is Docker unable to find the auth-svc directory during the build process?
Is there an issue with how the build context is being set in my docker-compose.yml file?
How can I correctly set up the docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile to ensure the build succeeds?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

@Lukman Is it so, even if you explicitly set the context in the docker-compose.yml? The docs say otherwise: "The <src> path is resolved relative to the build context." (emphasis by me)

Your config works for me although it's rather awkward to juggle context as you are. The error may (!?) be an issue with the build cache. Can you rebuild without cache (docker compose --file=./deploy/docker/docker-compose.yml build --no-cache) and then retry up?

Same issue did happen. Could you please say what was my juggle context
